# Parallel computing in R (if statement in foreach %dopar%)

Tags: r, if-statement, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I want to update my four variables (Z1, Z2, IVtmp$differror1, IVtmp$differror2) by groups (i) conditional on a if statement.

```
foreach(i=unique(IVtmp$scidx)) %dopar% {
  numerator=sum(P1new[IVtmp$scidx==i])+sum(P2new[DATA$scid==i])
  denominator=sum(P1old[IVtmp$scidx==i])+sum(P2old[DATA$scid==i])
  probab=exp(numerator-denominator)

  if (runif(1)<probab){
    Z1[DATA$scid==i]=e1new[DATA$scid==i]
    Z2[DATA$scid==i]=e2new[DATA$scid==i]
    IVtmp$differror1[IVtmp$scidx==i]=differror1new[IVtmp$scidx==i]
    IVtmp$differror2[IVtmp$scidx==i]=differror2new[IVtmp$scidx==i]
    change=change+1
  } else{
    Z1[DATA$scid==i]=e1old[DATA$scid==i]
    Z2[DATA$scid==i]=e2old[DATA$scid==i]
    IVtmp$differror1[IVtmp$scidx==i]=differror1old[IVtmp$scidx==i]
    IVtmp$differror2[IVtmp$scidx==i]=differror2old[IVtmp$scidx==i]
  }
}
```

But it seems I couldn't do if statement inside the foreah loop. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Steve. So, what I should add to the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "if" statement isn't the problem. The problem is that workers can't directly update variables on the master. The workers can only compute values that are sent to the master, and the master has to update its own variables with those values.

I don't think you're going to get good performance by running this problem in parallel, but you could try this:

```
library(doSNOW)
nw <- 4  # choose something reasonable for your computer
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(nw)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
iv <- unique(IVtmp$scidx)

probab <-
  foreach(i=iv, .combine='c') %dopar% {
    numerator=sum(P1new[IVtmp$scidx==i])+sum(P2new[DATA$scid==i])
    denominator=sum(P1old[IVtmp$scidx==i])+sum(P2old[DATA$scid==i])
    exp(numerator-denominator)
  }

for (i in iv) {
  if (runif(1)<probab[i]){
    Z1[DATA$scid==i]=e1new[DATA$scid==i]
    Z2[DATA$scid==i]=e2new[DATA$scid==i]
    IVtmp$differror1[IVtmp$scidx==i]=differror1new[IVtmp$scidx==i]
    IVtmp$differror2[IVtmp$scidx==i]=differror2new[IVtmp$scidx==i]
    change=change+1
  } else{
    Z1[DATA$scid==i]=e1old[DATA$scid==i]
    Z2[DATA$scid==i]=e2old[DATA$scid==i]
    IVtmp$differror1[IVtmp$scidx==i]=differror1old[IVtmp$scidx==i]
    IVtmp$differror2[IVtmp$scidx==i]=differror2old[IVtmp$scidx==i]
  }
}
```

This computes `probab` in parallel, and then updates the data structures sequentially. To do this, I converted `probab` to a vector.

Since computing `probab` doesn't seem very time consuming, I think your only hope for a speed up is to use *extreme chunking* in the parallel section:

```
library(itertools)
probab <-
  foreach(ivchunk=isplitVector(iv, chunks=nw), .combine='c') %dopar% {
    p <- double(length(ivchunk))
    for (i in ivchunk) {
      numerator=sum(P1new[IVtmp$scidx==i])+sum(P2new[DATA$scid==i])
      denominator=sum(P1old[IVtmp$scidx==i])+sum(P2old[DATA$scid==i])
      p[i] <- exp(numerator-denominator)
    }
    p
  }
```

This uses one task per worker to decrease overhead. It's an important technique, but I'm still not sure if it will give you decent performance over running sequentially in this case.

Comment: Thanks Steve. It does improve a bit. Just another general question of parallel computing. How many cores I should request? Is it as many as possible?

Comment: @BobbyWChung `detectCores` is a good starting point, but sometimes you should use less (other work being done on the computer or not enough memory), and sometimes you can use more (if the task isn't CPU bound). The best thing to do is to run some benchmarks.

Comment: Thank you, Steve!